Generating a Grayscale PDF through AEM Forms (oSGI)
I have written a DDX that merges two PDF documents (base PDF being XFA), on the same DDX I specified a footer that be stitched on the last few pages. Now my requirement is to make this entire PDF into Grayscale. I looked at DDX examples, found that Grayscale can only be applied at a PDF Portfolio. Any other suggestions how I can achieve this?
Could not find any ways to achieve this yet.
